# System Information in Browser

Tags: java, javascript, flash

We have a license key system which requires the MAC address of the network card of the PC. To make it easier for the user, I am looking into getting the MAC address (or some other similar system identification info) with a web page.

Do Flash (or Flex), JavaScript or Java Applets provide any APIs to query system information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link shows you how to get system information using JavaScript:

```
This article will show you how to write custom JavaScript objects 
that retrieve system information using the Windows Management 
Information (WMI) classes.
```

http://code.google.com/apis/desktop/articles/e3.html

Comment: ...for a Desktop Gadget. This information is (intentionally, and for a Good Reason) not visible to in-browser JavaScript. Would you like just any website to go messing with your system's internals?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

[how to get a client's MAC address from HttpServlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839973/how-to-get-a-clients-mac-address-from-httpservlet)

Comment: three links deep, there's this: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getHardwareAddress() which just might be what you're looking for. In a Java applet, this will probably require asking for additional permissions.