# Can I get the physical address of a client in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

To get the address of a client we use getRemoteAdd(). I have a requirement to get the Mac Address i.e., physical address of the client. Can we get the physical address of a client??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In TCP/IP You can't get the MAC Address

Details can be found on this thread
[how to get a client's MAC address from HttpServlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839973/how-to-get-a-clients-mac-address-from-httpservlet)