# How can i get the mac address of device either of mobile or system from browser application

Tags: security, web, browser, mac-address

For security reason i want to get the mac address of clients who are using our website, either you can provide a solution to get on client end or server end, but just we need mac address of clients who are accessing our website, please provide any solution for it, thanks

Comment: Not possible. Period.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost impossible, except in very specific scenarios. Have a look here: [how to get a client's MAC address from HttpServlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839973/how-to-get-a-clients-mac-address-from-httpservlet)

The only way you can probably do it is by making users install a browser plugin. Modern browsers won't let you access the MAC address of a device otherwise. Again, most users are not likely to do that. Also you should keep in mind that this is a privacy concern.

Even if you require that users install a plugin, and they agree on that, MAC addresses can very easily be spoofed. There are lots of programs that can do it in one click. You are not gaining any security by keeping track of the MAC addresses that connect to your website.