Does it possible to get the user client MAC address when they access my webapp
I have a website base on (spring boot and angular). Now i want to get client MAC address when they access to my website. I have found some related question but it very old. Can anybody tell me the way to get MAC address or if it impossible, please tell me why and share me related documentation
I have search this problem for a long time. But it can maybe work if client user at the same router with webapp. But it not my expected

Your question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/839973/2308683
