# How to get MAC Address in Firefox using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

The following code is working in IE,

```
var macAddress = "";
    var ipAddress = "";
    var computerName = "";
    var wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}");
    e = new Enumerator(wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True"));
    for(; !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
        var s = e.item();
        macAddress = s.MACAddress;
        ipAddress = s.IPAddress(0);
        computerName = s.DNSHostName;
    }
```

in Firefox It is not working because of ActiveX.

Comment: I don't know how to get the MAC address from JavaScript, but I sure hope the answer is "you can't do that".

Comment: possible duplicate of [MAC addresses in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript)

Comment: @Pekka — "How to get MAC Address in Firefox using Javascript?"

Comment: @Quentin ah, now that you mention it... :) +1 for dupe

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not support ActiveX technology for multiple reasons.

ActiveX is only available on Windows operating systems, and as a result webpages that require it will not work on Linux or Mac. ActiveX integration with the Windows operating system has made it a target for malicious software. Firefox uses plugins to view and use multimedia content embedded in web pages, and extensions to add new functions.

so what you need is a firefox plugin like this one: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mediawrap/