# How to get client MAC address by using javascript?

Tags: javascript

advance thanks those who gives me the great tips about how to find Physical address by using javascript.

Comment: It isn't possible, usually. (I suppose an ActiveX control could at a stretch.) Also, you probably shouldn't care.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10747/1846192.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps!

```
function networkInfo(){

var wmi = new ActiveXObject ("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
var service = wmi.ConnectServer(".");


e = new Enumerator(service.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True"));


for(; !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
    var s = e.item();
    var macAddress = unescape(s.MACAddress);

}

return macAddress;
}
```

Comment: That will only work in Internet Explorer, and only if the user decides to give your plugin permission.

Comment: thanks your support but i already try your code this code is only execute in IE8 but i need to compatible to all browser when client access my web application.