# It is possible to get the MAC address of a PC using a click button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mac-address

Is there any way to determine the MAC address of a PC? If so, how? The scenario is after the user clicks a certain button, the MAC address will get saved to a SQL Server database or displayed to a label. I'm trying to do this in a project I am working on in ASP.net MVC3. I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know where and how to start.

Comment: Have you seen [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript?rq=1)?

Comment: You can't get it from JavaScript, so I suggest updating your question to ask whether you can determine the client's MAC address *server-side* from an HTTP request.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added a little bit.

Comment: I've cleaned up the question a bit for you (you never put both a full stop *and* a question mark on a sentence in English, and generally there was a lot of repetition), and removed the irrelevant [tag:osx] and [tag:javascript] tags (since, again, the questino of whether you can do this with client-side JavaScript is covered by the link from nnnnnn above and is "no"). If I were you, I would still edit it to be much clearer about how you want to get the MAC address, but you chose not to, so...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for editing it.