# Is it possible to get Mac Address of client Device to uniquely identify website visitor using javascript?

Tags: javascript, mac-address

I have tried Navigator property of window in java script.I am trying it without any third party API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MAC addresses in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript)

Comment: Tl;Dr No, use cookies to identify users

Comment: you may be able to do it with a browser plugin - of course, whose going to install such pointless plugin :p