# how to insert system physical address into database

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

How can I insert system physical address into database on submission of form. when I register the for the with user details, automatically systems physical address should be registered to database. Please tel me how can I do it.

I am using - **HTML, javascript and PouchBD**

Below is my registration code. **register.html** in this I used javascript for valiodation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Insurance:Register User</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>        
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>

    <link href="css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/finalprivate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>



</head>
<body background="images/lbbackground.jpg" >
    <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">HOME</a>-->
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" >Survey
                            <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                <a  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Final Survey</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="finalprivate.html">Private</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li >
                                        <a href="finalcommercial.html">Commercial</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                <a  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Spot Survey</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="spotsurveyprivate.html">Private</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li >
                                        <a href="spotsurveycommercial.html">Commercial</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown ">
                                <a  href="reinspection.html">Re-inspection</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="reporthistory.html">Report History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="company.html">Insurance Companies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="personal.html">Personal Details</a></li>
                    <li><a href="accounts.html">Accounts</a></li>
                    <li  class="active"><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="logout.html" ">Logout</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="settings.html">Settings</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <article class="container" id="boxshadow" style="background-color:white;width:50%;">
        <form action="" method="POST" name="vform" id="regForm"> 
            <fieldset>
                <legend><strong>Register</strong></legend>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 ">
                        <!-- <label>User Name:</label> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <input class="form-control" name="fname" id="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
                        <div id="fname_error" name="val_error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div><br>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 ">
                        <!-- <label>User Name:</label> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <input class="form-control" name="lname" id="lname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
                        <div id="lname_error" name="val_error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div><br>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 ">
                        <!-- <label>User Name:</label> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <input class="form-control" name="uname" id="uname" type="text" placeholder="User Name">
                        <div id="uname_error" name="val_error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>   

                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 ">
                        <!-- <label>Password:</label> -->
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <input type="Password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                        <div id="password_error" name="val_error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 ">
                        <!-- <label>Password:</label> -->
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <input type="Password" class="form-control" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                        <div id="cpassword_error" name="val_error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 ">
                        <!-- <label>User Name:</label> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email ID">
                        <div id="email_error" name="val_error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 ">
                        <!-- <label>User Name:</label> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <input class="form-control" name="mobileno" id="mobileno" type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number">
                        <div id="mobileno_error" name="val_error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 ">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
                        <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary" name="click" id="submitbtn" value="Register" >
                    </div>
                    <span id="message" style="color: red;"></span>

                </div>
                <br>                     

            </fieldset>

        </form>
    </article>
    </body>
     <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>
    <script src="js\pouchdb-6.1.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/serial.js"></script>

    <script src="js/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/memorystream.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pouchdb.replication-stream.js"></script>
    <script src="js/register.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

$("#regForm").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

 var fname = document.forms["vform"]['fname'];
      var lname = document.forms["vform"]['lname'];
      var uname = document.forms["vform"]['uname'];
      var password = document.forms["vform"]['password'];
      var cpassword = document.forms["vform"]['cpassword'];
      var email = document.forms["vform"]['email'];
      var mobile = document.forms["vform"]['mobileno'];

      //Validation
      var fname_error = document.getElementById("fname_error");
      var lname_error = document.getElementById("lname_error");
      var uname_error = document.getElementById("uname_error");
      var password_error = document.getElementById("password_error");
      var cpassword_error = document.getElementById("cpassword_error");
      var email_error = document.getElementById("email_error");
      var mobileno_error = document.getElementById("mobileno_error");

      //Setting All event Listners
      fname.addEventListener("blur", fnameVerify, true);
      lname.addEventListener("blur", lnameVerify, true);
      uname.addEventListener("blur", unameVerify, true);
      password.addEventListener("blur", passwordVerify, true);
      cpassword.addEventListener("blur", cpasswordVerify, true);
      email.addEventListener("blur", emailVerify, true);
      mobileno.addEventListener("blur", mobilenoVerify, true);
      Validate();
});


      //Validating
      function Validate()
      {

        if (fname.value == "")
        {
          //fname.style.border="1px solid red"              
          fname_error.innerHTML="<span style='color:red'> First  Name is required";
          fname.focus();
          return false; 
        }

        if (lname.value == "")
        {
          //lname.style.border="1px solid red"
          lname_error.innerHTML="<span style='color:red'>Last Name is required";
          lname.focus();
          return false; 
        }

        if (uname.value == "")
        {
          //uname.style.border="1px solid red"
          uname_error.innerHTML="<span style='color:red'>User Name is required";
          uname.focus();
          return false; 
        }

        if (password.value == "")
        {
          //password.style.border="1px solid red"
          password_error.innerHTML="<span style='color:red'>Password is required";
          password.focus();
          return false; 
        }

        if (password.value != cpassword.value)
        {
          //cpassword.style.border="1px solid red"
          cpassword_error.innerHTML="<span style='color:red'>Password dont match";   
          cpassword.focus();           
          return false; 
        }

        if(email.value == "")
        {
          //email.style.border="1px solid red"
          email_error.innerHTML="<span style='color:red'>Email is required";
          email.focus();
          return false; 
        }

        var x = document.forms["vform"]["email"].value;
        var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
            //alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
            email_error.innerHTML="<span style='color:red'>Not a valid e-mail address";
            email.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if(mobileno.value == "")
        {
          //mobileno.style.border="1px solid red"
          mobileno_error.innerHTML="<span style='color:red'>Mobile number is required";
          mobileno.focus();
          return false; 
        }
        var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
        if (mobileno.value.match(numbers)) 
        {
          //return true;
        }
        else
        {
          //mobileno.style.border="1px solid red"
          mobileno_error.innerHTML="<span style='color:red'> Mobile number must be numbers only";  
          mobileno.focus();  
          return false;
        }

        if(mobileno.value.length !=10)
        {
          //mobileno.style.border="1px solid red"
          mobileno_error.innerHTML="<span style='color:red'> Mobile number must be 10 digit";
          mobileno.focus();
          return false; 
        }


            //regEvent();
            addregister();

      }


        function fnameVerify()
        {
          if(fname.value !="")
          {
            fname_error.innerHTML = "";
            return true;
          }
        }

        function lnameVerify()
        {
          if(lname.value != "")
          {
            lname_error.innerHTML= "";
            return true;
          }
        }

        function unameVerify()
        {
          if(uname.value != "")
          {
            uname_error.innerHTML= "";
            return true;
          }
        }

        function passwordVerify()
        {
          if(password.value != "")
          {
            password_error.innerHTML= "";
            return true;
          }
        }

        function cpasswordVerify()
        {
          if(cpassword.value != "")
          {
            cpassword_error.innerHTML= "";
            return true;
          }
        }

        function emailVerify()
        {
          if(email.value != "")
          {
            email_error.innerHTML= "";
            return true;
          }
        }

        function mobilenoVerify()
        {
          if(mobileno.value != "")
          {
            mobileno_error.innerHTML = "";
            return true;
          }
        } 


</script>
</html>
```

Below is my javascript code to save the data to **pouchDB**. register.js

```
var db=new PouchDB('register_details');

function addregister(){
  var f=document.getElementById('fname').value;
  var l=document.getElementById('lname').value;
  var u=document.getElementById('uname').value;
  var p=document.getElementById('password').value;
  var e=document.getElementById('email').value;
  var m=document.getElementById('mobileno').value;
  //console.log(f,l,u,p,e,m);

  doc={
_id:u,
fname:f, 
lname:l,
password:p,
email:e,
mobileno:m
  }
 db.put(doc,function(error,response){

if(!error){
  //document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="inserted";
  alert('Registered successfully!');

    document.getElementById('fname').value='';
    document.getElementById('lname').value='';
    document.getElementById('uname').value='';
    document.getElementById('password').value='';
    document.getElementById('cpassword').value='';
    document.getElementById('email').value='';
    document.getElementById('mobileno').value='';



}
else{
  alert('User name already exist!');
  //document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=" Not inserted";
}
  });
}
```

Comment: I updated above please see that..

Comment: you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

No. If you want to access MAC Address using JavaScript only then its not possbile . If you are using Java code (applet) or on IE browser using ActiveX control then you can get it.

JavaScript don't have ability to get the MAC address.

Comment: can u tel me how can we do it using nodejs

Comment: @Carlos JavaScript works on client side and NodeJS works on server side but both are same . Important thing is that client-side language can not access those information which can be a vulnerability for client.

You can access MAC address using NodeJS but that MAC will be of server on which your NodeJS code is running. So its impossible to get the client's MAC address.

Can you please tell me that what you want to do with MAC address.