# How to get MAC address of client System in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mac-address

I am getting answer in PHP but its not working because of session.

```
//Get the ipconfig details using system commond  
system('ipconfig /all');  
// Capture the output into a variable  
$mycomsys=ob_get_contents();  
// Clean (erase) the output buffer  

$find_mac = "Physical"; //find the "Physical" & Find the position of Physical text  
$pmac = strpos($mycomsys, $find_mac);  
// Get Physical Address  
$macaddress=substr($mycomsys,($pmac+36),17);  
ob_clean();  
//Display Mac Address
exec("/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep HWaddr", $output);
print_r( $output);die();
```

This fulfils my requirement but not running for my applications, So I am in need of the same in JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MAC addresses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript)

Comment: http://codingresource.blogspot.in/2010/02/get-client-mac-address-ip-address-using.html  Check out this