# can get client machine mac address from web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to get client machine mac address details while using my web application is that possible ?? or else i need to differentiate client machine by each while using my web application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MAC addresses in JavaScript
?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MAC addresses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript)