# How can i find the mac address on client side i.e. for web browsers?

Tags: javascript, angular, mac-address

I need to manage the login activity for this I need the mac address of devices. Using Angular or Javascript?

I have tried `getmac npm module`.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is NO.

With plain Javascript there is no option to get such an information.

Comment: did you really just looked at the  stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript and got @GateKiller 's answer and changed the wording? lol

Comment: Actually you can using  "JavaScript and Active X control of Microsoft" - Ad Kahn

Comment: Your wording is wrong. Yes you can do it with plain Javascript, you can't do it with Javascript only. Big difference.

Comment: I really need some help to find mac address but i am not actually near any solution. I have tried npm macaddress as well, but it didn't help me. Can anyone please suggest me a better way actually any way to find the mac address using plain javascript?