# is it possible to get the mac address using the javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mac-address

I need the mac addresses of system for login using the JavaScript ,is their possible to get Mac addresses using the JavaScript?

Comment: no. this is not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MAC addresses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No!
Javascript is quite a high level language and doesn't have access to this sort of information. And such information via JavaScript would be a security vulnerability as well.