# get the mac-address of client's machine or the private address in sub network

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the address mac of the mahine client on my  application to check if the user have been visited this application or this is the first time

Comment: That's a challenging question... I think that ECMAScript/jscript  engines embedded with navigators will not have access to the client network hardware interfaces, i'll do some search.

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript

You cannot get access to the MAC address because this would house security issues.