# os.networkinterfaces returns null

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to get the client side mac address, and I tried to use node.js inner module os.networkInterfaces() to get mac address. I can compile sucessfully but I always got empty object. And I tried the both ways below:

```
import {networkInterfaces} from 'os';
...
const mac = networkInterfaces();
```

or :

```
const os = require('os');
const mac = os.networkInterfaces();
```

Does any one have similar experience? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MAC addresses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript)

Comment: It seems there is no way. Acctually I want to bind client hardware information and the user account. So I need the web application to grab something from the browser, like hardware mac address or disc serial number. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use nodejs code in a browser application.

Also, a mac address is not something that is accessible within the browser, that would be a security/privacy breach.

Comment: Acctually I want to bind client hardware information and the user account. So I need the web application to grab something from the browser, like hardware mac address or disc serial number. Is there anyway to do this?